# Function responsible for opening and resizing photo does not work

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to pack code responsible for opening, resizing images into function as I will do this action a lot of times. 
I have this couple of lines which are needed to show image in gui:

```
img = Image.open("images/cola.jpg")
img = img.resize((40, 40), Image.ANTIALIAS)
photoImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
ColaLabel = ttk.Label(gui, image=photoImg)
ColaLabel.grid(column=6, row=0)
Colala = ttk.Label(gui, text='30')
Colala.grid(column=5, row=0)
```

And GUI looks like this:

[image]

I tried to make the function this way:

```
def createGUIProduct(path: str):
    img = Image.open(path)
    img = img.resize((40, 40), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    return ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
```

And calling it by this way:

```
ColaLabel = ttk.Label(gui, image=createGUIProduct("images/cola.jpg"))
ColaLabel.grid(column=6, row=0)
Colala = ttk.Label(gui, text='30')
Colala.grid(column=5, row=0)
```

And the result is:

[image]

EDIT:

After modifing function:

```
def createGUIProduct(path: str):
    global photoImage
    img = Image.open(path)
    img = img.resize((40, 40), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    photoImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    return photoImage
```

And calling two products by the same way:

```
ColaLabel = ttk.Label(gui, image=createGUIProduct("images/cola.jpg"))
ColaLabel.grid(column=6, row=0)
Colala = ttk.Label(gui, text='30')
Colala.grid(column=5, row=0)


WodaLabel = ttk.Label(gui, image=createGUIProduct("images/woda.jpg"))
WodaLabel.grid(column=8, row=0)
Wodala = ttk.Label(gui, text='31')
Wodala.grid(column=7, row=0)
```

Only one show up:

[image]

Comment: `PhotoImage` used in function may have problem with Garbage Collector which remove images when they are assigned to local variable in function. So maybe this is your problem. Inside function create `PhotoImage` and assign to global variable before you return it.

Comment: @furas ye, that's it, but now if I have two products like Cola only one image show up. Edited the question.

Comment: easiest way is to create a list outside your function, and append the `Photoimage` object to the list.

Comment: @HenryYik what it is gonna do? Could you give me an example?

Comment: you have to create list for all images. Or create function which creates Label with Image and it assigns image to this label like in example at the bottom of page http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

Comment: Got it. It works. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

you used different function name, it should be createGUIImage() not createGUIProduct()

change

`ColaLabel = ttk.Label(gui, image=createGUIProduct("images/cola.jpg"))`

to:

```
ColaLabel = ttk.Label(gui, image=createGUIImage("images/cola.jpg"))
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed the name of the function while creating this question.